# Can i follow list items in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, list

Well, can i perform this? I keep my site news in list. And want to provide user some additional function to follow some of this news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can follow List Items.. The functionality is called "Alert Me"

Following article should help:

[SharePoint 2013 - Alert Me - Option](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prasannabalajim/archive/2013/03/28/sharepoint-2013-alert-me-option.aspx)

Comment: thx. But can I do this programmatically from c# code? I want to perform this functionality from wcf service. Ex. user likes some news (list items) and at this time he follows this news (or "allerts" this news)

Comment: Yes you can configure them programmatically. It should be like [Programmatically Creating Alerts in SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-creating-alerts-in-sharepoint-2010/). The link is for 2010 but should work for 2013 as well